# How to hide arrow on right side of a Toolbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolbar

Figured out how to hide the grippy dots on the left side, now how do I hide that add/remove buttons drop-down arrow on the right side?

Answer (score 24):

Google is full with the answer to this:

```cs
private void ToolBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolBar toolBar = sender as ToolBar;
    var overflowGrid = toolBar.Template.FindName("OverflowGrid", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
    if (overflowGrid != null)
    {
            overflowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    var mainPanelBorder = toolBar.Template.FindName("MainPanelBorder", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
    if (mainPanelBorder != null)
    {
        mainPanelBorder.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
```

And assign this method to your toolbar Loaded event.

Comment: Tried searching google, couldn't find it. And this leaves a gap on the right side where the button once was... anyway to fix that?

Comment: For the gap `OverflowMode="Never"` should remove it if I remember well.

Comment: @Andrei: What's that a property of? Where do I set it? **Edit:** Nevermind. Found it. But it doesn't remove the gap.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't realize in the beginning what gap exactly you were talking about. When I removed the overflow for myself, I didn't noticed that gap so I didn't care about it. I don't see a simple way to remove that gap at this moment, so retemplating the whole toolbar (as H.B. answered) might be the only option.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the gap, the gap was because of the margin of the main panel.

Comment: Appears to work. Still seems a bit hacky though. Don't like this `FindName` stuff.

Comment: Well, the philosophy says it is indeed hacky, but removing the overflow button is simply not exposed through a property (like with the left grip). That means the look designed for the toolbar was not intended to miss the overflow component. To get rid of it, you need to define a new style/look for toolbar, a look that does not have the overflow and this implies rewriting the *entire* control template (as H.B. proposed), but you'll have to include in the template all the toolbar's functionality. FindName it's not hacky by itself (in fact it is very often used in custom control development).

Answer (score 6):

Assign following method to your toolbar SizeChanged event.

```
    private void ToolBar_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolBar toolBar = sender as ToolBar;
        var overflowGrid = toolBar.Template.FindName("OverflowGrid", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
        if (overflowGrid != null)
        {
            overflowGrid.Visibility = toolBar.HasOverflowItems ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        var mainPanelBorder = toolBar.Template.FindName("MainPanelBorder", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
        if (mainPanelBorder != null)
        {
            var defaultMargin = new Thickness(0, 0, 11, 0);
            mainPanelBorder.Margin = toolBar.HasOverflowItems ?defaultMargin: new Thickness(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works perfect for horizontal toolbars. for vertical toolbars the arrow appears not below the last button, but beside it (on right, if toolbar is on left side of the window).

Comment: in case of Orientation.Vertical the margin should be Thickness(0, 0, 0, 11)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** *Closed the gap too.*
**Edit2:** *Fixed missing resources.*
Alternatively you can use a copy of the style with the earlier mentioned visibility changed and the margin on the right removed, all those resources belong to the style/template:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToolBarHorizontalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFF" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F7F7F7" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonVerticalBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ECECEC" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#A0A0A0" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonHover" Color="#C2E0FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarGripper" Color="#C6C3C6"/>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarVerticalOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarToggleButtonVerticalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="6" Margin="2,7,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="7">
                            <Path Data="M 1.5 1 L 1.5 6" Stroke="White"/>
                            <Path Data="M 0.5 0 L 0.5 5" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            <Path Data="M 3.5 0.5 L 7 3.5 L 4 6.5 Z" Fill="White"/>
                            <Path Data="M 3 -0.5 L 6 2.5 L 3 5.5 Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarGripper}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToolBarVerticalBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFF" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F7F7F7" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ECECEC" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#A0A0A0" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="7" Margin="7,2,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="6">
                            <Path Data="M 1 1.5 L 6 1.5" Stroke="White"/>
                            <Path Data="M 0 0.5 L 5 0.5" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            <Path Data="M 0.5 4 L 6.5 4 L 3.5 7 Z" Fill="White"/>
                            <Path Data="M -0.5 3 L 5.5 3 L 2.5 6 Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarGripper}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarMenuBorder" Color="#808080"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarSubMenuBackground" Color="#FDFDFD"/>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0,4,4" Viewport="0,0,4,4" ViewportUnits="Absolute" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                        <DrawingGroup>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="M 1 1 L 1 3 L 3 3 L 3 1 z"/>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource ToolBarGripper}" Geometry="M 0 0 L 0 2 L 2 2 L 2 0 z"/>
                                        </DrawingGroup>
                                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                </DrawingBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeAll"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarMainPanelBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,11,0"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3,3,3,3"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarWithoutOverflowBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarHorizontalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Margin="3,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid x:Name="OverflowGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Hidden">
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="OverflowButton" ClickMode="Press" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOverflowOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding HasOverflowItems}" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle}"/>
                            <Popup x:Name="OverflowPopup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsOverflowOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="false">
                                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                                    <Border x:Name="ToolBarSubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ToolBarMenuBorder}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource ToolBarSubMenuBackground}" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <ToolBarOverflowPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Focusable="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" WrapWidth="200"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="MainPanelBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarMainPanelBorderStyle}" Margin="0">
                            <DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                <Thumb x:Name="ToolBarThumb" Margin="-3,-1,0,0" Padding="6,5,1,6" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarThumbStyle}" Width="10"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ToolBarHeader" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,4,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ToolBarPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="0,1,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsOverflowOpen" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Header" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToolBarTray.IsLocked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="OverflowPopup" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" TargetName="Shdw" Value="true"/>
                            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Grid" Value="1,3,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OverflowButton" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarVerticalOverflowButtonStyle}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="10"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="-1,-3,0,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="5,6,6,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="PART_ToolBarPanel" Value="1,0,2,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" TargetName="OverflowGrid" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" TargetName="OverflowGrid" Value="Bottom"/>
                            <Setter Property="Placement" TargetName="OverflowPopup" Value="Right"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="MainPanelBorder" Value="0,0,0,11"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarVerticalBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

After you embedded that somewhere you can set the style of the toolbar:

```
<ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarWithoutOverflowBarStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Wow... I can't believe it requires that much work to have a plain toolbar.

Comment: If you don't want the grip and the dropdown, why are you using a toolbar?  You could just use a panel of some kind.

Comment: @Ralph: It's not much work if you have Expression Blend, it can extract the default template, that is what i did here. Blend is quite useful for templates, styles and the like.

Answer (score 3):

I have searching four hours to do this correctly with MVVM (so no code behind).

The most important thing is the "visibility collapsed" after ToggleButton and after `ToolBarOverflowPanel` (I have set the background color to black for my nav example).

[image: See here: black toolbar whithout left and right stupid thingies]

Here is the code that you can set on your toolbar by `"<toolbar Style="{StaticResource ToolBar}" Background="Black">...</ToolBar>`

Here is the code for the style:

```
    <Style x:Key="Toolbar" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"  CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <DockPanel >
                        <ToggleButton Visibility="Collapsed"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="False" ClickMode="Press">
                            <Popup x:Name="OverflowPopup" AllowsTransparency="true" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsOverflowOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" StaysOpen="false" Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="pink" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="pink">
                                    <ToolBarOverflowPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel" Margin="2" WrapWidth="200" Focusable="true"  FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ToolBarPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="0,1,2,2"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I looked for a while too and didn't find an elegant XAML solution, this works great, I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for that one. I removed the x:Key="Toolbar" and stuck it in the Resources section to declutter the <toolbar … declaration. Also removed the Background and BorderBrush setting

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure that you actually need a toolbar or kind of a component looks like a menubar. Here is just what I want:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu1" Padding="10 4">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1"/>
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Menu2" Padding="10 4">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1"/>
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <...>
 </Grid>
```

It may not fit to your case. Just I would like to share mine.