# Aligning Item in Toolstrip

Tags: wpf, vb.net, toolbar

Until now I alway's used Winforms for the GUI of my Project. Now I want to migrate one of the older projects finally to `WPF`.

Here I have a little problem with the `ToolBar` items.
That's how the first part of the migrated GUI looks at present

[image: Current look]

What I really want, is that first: the ? Button is aligned strictly to the right of the Bar
and second: gray-Button(? don't even know how its called) at the right side should not be displayed.
How can I achieve both things?

In terms of aligning the Button to the right of the toolbar I tried using the vertical Align and margins, but both without success.

Here's the code for the corresponding part of the user-interface

```
 <ToolBar Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <MenuItem Header="Some text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="524">

            </MenuItem>
            <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <MenuItem Header="" Margin="0" Width="28" Height="25">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="{DynamicResource ImageSource1}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>

                    <MenuItem x:Name="miAbout" Header="About.."></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="miDocu" Header="Documentation"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="miBugreport" Header="Bug report"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="miFeatureRequest" Header="Feature request"></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ToolBar>
```

EDIT:
thanks to  stsurs linked answer and this method, take from it:

```
Private Sub ToolBar_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ToolBar1.Loaded
    Dim toolbar As ToolBar = sender
    Dim overflowGrid = CType(toolbar.Template.FindName("OverflowGrid", toolbar), FrameworkElement)
    If Not (overflowGrid Is Nothing) Then
        overflowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
    End If

    Dim mainPanelBorder = CType(toolbar.Template.FindName("MainPanelBorder", toolbar), FrameworkElement)
    If Not (mainPanelBorder Is Nothing) Then
        toolbar.Margin = New Thickness(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

At least the overflow-section to the right isn't displayed any more, that just leaves the problem of aligning the image-button to the right of the the bar.

Comment: the arrow is called OverFlow indicator.

Comment: and you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662428/how-to-hide-arrow-on-right-side-of-a-toolbar

Comment: thanks, that leaves just part 1 on how to align the Button to the right of the Toolbar

Comment: can you fix your code so i can look further ?